# iOS native IKEv2 client and ECDSA server certificates

Tags: iphone, vpn

I am trying to connect my iPhone (iOS 13.6) to my new Cisco ASA via an IKEv2 IPSec tunnel and I found that the iOS native VPN client connects correctly in case of RSA based certificate on the server side and does not connect in case of ECDSA based certificate. Both certificates are issued by a public CA (Sectigo RSA DV and Sectigo ECC DV) with the same CommonName. Error description: "User authentication failed".

Is the iOS IKEv2 client implementation compatible with ECDSA server certificates?

Connection details on the iPhone side: manual IKEv2 configuration without profiles. Server and the Remote-ID contain the FQDN of the VPN server, user authentication with a username/password pair.

Cisco AnyConnect iOS client works great with both algorithms. Strongswan client for GNU/Linux works too.

Comment: Seeing the same behaviour when trying to connect from macOS 12.5 (Monterey) to Strongswan server with ECDSA certificate from Let's Encrypt (RSA cert works fine). Console contains the following error message from NEIKEv2Provider
```
[IKE_AUTH R resp1 7B329F48049BB49F-A8F190E8330E201F] Initiator packet authentication method 
    Payload Type = Auth
    Authentication Protocol = ECDSA256
    Authentication Data = 64:{length = 64, bytes = 0x23e833af 46e84d20 85c6e0ec edb6d193 ... 56bbba37 691c3900 } does not match proposal RSASignature
```
Seems to be an Apple IKEv2 client's limitation.